# Angular 2 - creating alert in service

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this alert:

contractorService.ts:

```
public showConfirm(title: string, message: string, cancelBtnTxt: string, confirmBtnTxt: string, confirmFunc: any, cancelFunc: any): void {
    console.log("confirmFunc: ", confirmFunc);
    const confirm = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: title,
      message: message,
      buttons: [
        {
          text: cancelBtnTxt,
          handler: () => {
            cancelFunc();
          }
        },
        {
          text: confirmBtnTxt,
          handler: () => {
            confirmFunc();
          }
        }
      ]
    });
    confirm.present();
  }
```

I have a service, I think I might need to call it from other places. How can I pass in the confirm and cancel functions with parameters.

```
requestComponent.ts:

public test(): void {
    console.log('test');
}
```

some other function in `requestComponent.ts:`

```
someFunc(): void {
    this.service.showConfirm('title', 'message', 'Cancel', 'OK, this.test, null);
}
```

The above works, but then I tried:

```
public test(param: any): void {
    console.log('test: ', param); // param is undefined.
}

someFunc(): void {
    this.service.showConfirm('title', 'message', 'Cancel', 'OK, this.test.bind('test param'), null);
}
```

but I get: test: undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try the following:

`this.service.showConfirm('title', 'message', 'Cancel', 'OK, () => this.test('test param'), null);`

I always feel this is the most elegant way for doing this kind of things.

Answer (score 1):

You should pass the arguments as follows :

```
this.service.showConfirm('title', 'message', 'Cancel', 'OK', this.test.bind(this, 'Yes'), null);
```

Notice the parameter `this.test.bind(this, 'Yes')`. You should be passing `this` context (component) to the called function, because your `test` method exists on component.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.contractorService.showConfirm("Continue?", "Your credit card will be charged", "Cancel", "OK", this.test.bind(this.test, 'a'), this.cancel);
```

So I guess we need to pass a function with arguments. Above is working.

Comment: You need to pass `this` as argument as opposed to `this.test` for `this.test.bind()`

Comment: No. I have a function. I don't have a function within a function. test is a function itself.

Comment: But that `test` function is inside component correct? Your service has to call it like `compInstance.test()`. With your approach it would try to call `compInstance.test.test()`

Comment: why are we talking about this lol I have answered my own question :)

Comment: Because that seems to be incorrect. test() has to be executed in the context of component instance.

Comment: lol I love your enthusiasm :) Thank you for all of your help.

Comment: I've edited my question, I hope that clears what I was going for. I want to accept my own answer :D